# Handwritten script on two scroll paintings

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Could someone help translate what’s written on these two scroll paintings please?

[image: one]

[image: two]

Comment: 景儒心于黑龙江 on the first scroll.

Comment: 志学写于xx雪园癸酉年 on the second scroll.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, any idea what the seal marks say?

Comment: 追x古人之新意 i can tell the components of the x one but i cannot think out what it is for now. Let me do some searching.

Comment: 志学笔印 the bottom one.

Comment: Wow thank you 志学笔印 works match mine exactly, very similar in composition from what I just viewed.

Comment: @TooskyHierot you can write an answer with the calligraphy text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Seal decipherment

---

[image]

I think this actually might be a character, which is 「夒」.

> Glyph evolution of 「夒」:
>
> <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2336
> [合集35269](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=35269&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2043
> [合集24963](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=24963&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)・[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state))
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 秦子簋
> 故宮05.6</kbd><kbd>[三國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms)・[魏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Wei)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 魏上尊號奏
> 秦漢魏晉篆</kbd><kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>

---

[image]

張ＸＸ印 (Other characters are too faded out)

---

[image]

追摹古人出新意

---

[image]

干（城）

---

[image]

（志）⿱龸子（學）茟（筆）印

Comment: Thanks for deciphering, very unusual that the figural stamp is a character. I would've never known.

Comment: @amadeus it's a guess, I'm not sure. If 夒 describes the artist's personality or their paintings/works then I would say that the stamp is really a character.